# Maximum Length of a filename on Win7

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application which allows users to download a file. In doing so it asks users to provide the name to it in textbox. The upper limit of this text box is 200 characters. When i try to download a file on my Win7 system while accessing this application i do not get the whole 200 characters, instead i get only 158. I went through some articles that suggest that the max character length of a filename for Win7 is 256 characters and also the location (whole path) of the download gets accounted for in this. Also this 158 characters includes the location where this file is chosen to save, in the browser.

Please suggest..

Comment: Suggest you show us some code.